# Create a dictionary for each row

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have an excel [file](http://administracja.sgh.waw.pl/en/dsm/schedules/session/Documents/SMMB%2020172%20-%20changes%2017.05.18.xls) which for each line there is an event, out of this excel file I would like to create a dictionary with for example

```
{ 'summary' : '223051-0011 Advanced Macroeconomics I',
  'location' : 'C5-d'
}
```

and so on.

The problem I have is that somehow I cannot iterate through every column, and for each of them create a separate dictionary, this is how I am trying to solve this challenge:

```
excel_file = pd.read_excel(
'http://administracja.sgh.waw.pl/en/dsm/schedules/session/Documents/SMMB%2020172%20-%20changes%2017.05.18.xls',
encoding='utf-8', header=1)

n = 0
while n < len(excel_file.index) - 1:
    events = excel_file.iloc[n]
    n += 1

event_summary = {}
event_start = {}
event_end = {}
location = {}
event = {}

for row in events:
    event['summary'] = events.iloc[0]

    event_start['dateTime'] = events[6].replace(';', ' ') + events[3]
    print(event_start)

    event_end['dateTime'] = events[6].replace(';', ' ') + events[4]
```

Comment: What is the structure of the XL file?  A sample row will help.

Comment: @Sid there is a link to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick approach:

```py
excel_file = pd.read_excel('http://administracja.sgh.waw.pl/en/dsm/schedules/session/Documents/SMMB%2020172%20-%20changes%2017.05.18.xls',
                           encoding='utf-8')
# note header=1 was removed as this infers the incorrect header
index_dict = dict()
for index, row in excel_file.iterrows():
    index_dict.update({index: {'subject': row['Subject'],
                               'place': row['Place']}})
```

This gives you a master dictionary mapping row index to a summary dictionary with the information you're interested in. For example `index_dict[0]` gives the dictionary of summary information for the first row, and so on. You can do any additional preprocessing in the above for loop.

To do this even more efficiently for the whole dataframe in one go:

```py
index_dict = excel_file.to_dict(orient='index')
```

This gives a master dictionary with entries:

```py
{0: {'Date': '11-06-18;',
  'Day': 'Monday',
  'End': '15:10',
  'Place': 'A-210',
  'Start': '13:30',
  'Subject': '223051-0011 Advanced Macroeconomics I',
  'Teacher': 'Adamowicz Elżbieta - 0011'},
 1: {'Date': '18-06-18;',
  'Day': 'Monday',
  'End': '15:10',
  'Place': 'C-5d comp.',
  'Start': '13:30',
  'Subject': '223471-0131 Event History Analysis With SAS',
  'Teacher': 'Frątczak Ewa-0131'}, ...
}
```